# Change focus to next input field when max length is reached

Tags: jsf, focus, richfaces

i want to change the focus of fechaI, after it reaches to the max length (which is 2) and set the focus on mesI. Thanks in advance and sorry for my english, not my main.

```
<h:form id:form>
...
<h:inputText id="fechaI" value="#{solicitud.fechaI}" maxlength="2" size="2">
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="fechaI"/> 
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="mesI" value="#{solicitud.mesI}" maxlength="2" size="2" >
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="mesI"/> 
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="anoI" value="#{solicitud.anoI}" maxlength="4" size="4" >
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="anoI"/> 
</h:inputText>
...
</h:form>
```

UPDATE of my code, still not working:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputText id="fechaI" value="#{solicitud.fechaI}" maxlength="2" size="2" tabindex="1"/>
    <h:inputText id="mesI" value="#{solicitud.mesI}" maxlength="2" size="2" tabindex="2" />
    <h:inputText id="anoI" value="#{solicitud.anoI}" maxlength="4" size="4"  tabindex="3" />
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
  $('input[maxlength][tabindex]').on('keyup', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length == $this.attr('maxlength')) {
        $('input[maxlength][tabindex=' + ($this.attr('tabindex') + 1) + ']').focus();
    }
  });
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JavaScript and RichFaces's ***#{rich:element}*** expression like below.

```
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="fechaI" value="" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeyup="if(this.value.length >= this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {#{rich:element('mesI')}.focus()}"/>
        <h:inputText id="mesI" value="" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeyup="if(this.value.length >= this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {#{rich:element('anoI')}.focus()}"/>
        <h:inputText id="anoI" value="" maxlength="4" size="4"/>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: I recommend adding `&amp;&amp; event.keyCode != 9 &amp;&amp; event.keyCode != 16` (9 is tab, and 16 is shift-tab) to the if clause, so that the field can still be tabbed into even when full. Otherwise it cannot be edited just using the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is no JSF facility or component for this. You'd need some JavaScript.

First give the inputs a `tabindex` as well

```
<h:inputText ... maxlength="2" tabindex="1" />
<h:inputText ... maxlength="2" tabindex="2" />
<h:inputText ... maxlength="4" tabindex="3" />
```

Then you can get it to work by executing this little shot of jQuery on DOM ready

```
$('input[maxlength][tabindex]').on('keyup', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length == $this.attr('maxlength')) {
        $("input[maxlength][tabindex='" + (parseInt($this.attr('tabindex')) + 1) + "']").focus();
    }
});
```

If you're using an older version of RichFaces which don't include jQuery 1.7.x, then use [`jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but im sorry im kinda new doing integration of jsf with java script, can you tell me the sintax where i hace to insert this: 

$('input[maxlength][tabindex]').on('keyup', function(){ ....
});

Comment: It's not different from normal HTML. Keep in mind that JSF is "just" a HTML code generator. Open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. See, it's all just HTML. JavaScript has got to run there. Put the script in a `.js` file or a `<script>` tag the usual HTML way.

Comment: i did as you said but its not working still, doesn autofocus after reaching maxlength:
    <h:form id="form">
     <h:inputText ... maxlength="2" tabindex="1"/>
 <h:inputText ... maxlength="2" tabindex="2"/>
 <h:inputText ... maxlength="4" tabindex="3"/>
    </h:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
      $('input[maxlength][tabindex]').on('keyup', function() {
  $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val().length == $this.attr('maxlength')) {
      $('input[maxlength][tabindex=' + ($this.attr('tabindex') + 1) + ']').focus();
  }
   });
    //]]>
    </script>

Comment: As said, if you're using an older RichFaces version which don't include jQuery 1.7.x, then use `live()` instead of `on()`. It should also be obvious enough if you have checked for any JavaScript error messages in the browser's builtin JavaScript console.

Comment: @Willy, the parseInt is required for sum. The post has been edited.